# How to split a bounty between $\geq$2 users?

Tags: support, bounty

I just see the +X link, I wish to give out two X/2's. (three actually, but i have low rep)

Im asking because i think I've seen split bounties awarded.

Edit: So if I dont have enough reputation, can I repeal a 100 point bounty, and give away two successive 50 point bounties instead?

Comment: I don't believe split bounties can be awarded... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users Perhaps what you've seen is multiple bounties offered on the same question, awarded to different users?

Comment: I think you'll just have to award them one at a time.  Award one, start a new bounty, then award the other as soon as you can.

Comment: "can I repeal a 100 point bounty" - nope. Rep lost from bounties can no longer be returned to you. Just award that one you now have, and maybe award another bounty later, when you have the rep to give.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps you've seen something like what happened on the question [Given two basis sets for a finite Hilbert space, does an unbiased vector exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28413/given-two-basis-sets-for-a-finite-hilbert-space-does-an-unbiased-vector-exist).  Three of the answers there have been awarded a bounty, 2 by the OP and 1 by someone else.  These were all separate bounties.  You're free to start a second bounty on the same question.  There are certain limits (like only one bounty at a time), but the FAQ should fill you in on those.  Actually splitting a single bounty is impossible, as Arturo said.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation with this question: "[Is there a nice way to characterize this subset of $\mathbb{Z}_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34195/is-there-a-nice-way-to-characterize-this-subset-of-z-n)"  I felt like the answer to my question was obtained by combining a comment and two answers.  I ended up awarding the bounty to the more helpful of the two answers, and then I upvoted several answers of the other two users to *different* questions - answers that I liked but hadn't upvoted yet.  This enabled me to reward the other two in the form of rep.  Of course, it helped that the other two were 10,000+ rep users with lots of good answers to choose from.  I would have preferred to award bounty rep, but as others have pointed out, that wasn't possible.  The solution I came up with seemed like a reasonable alternative.